# How do try and <|> functions from parsers lib work

Tags: parsing, haskell

(I use `trifecta` parser lib). I'm trying to make a parser that parses integers into `Right` and literal sequences (alphabet, numeral symbols and "-" are allowed) into `Left`:

```
*Lib>  parseString myParser mempty "123 qwe 123qwe 123-qwe-"
Success [Right 123,Left "qwe",Left "123qwe",Left "123-qwe-"]
```

That is what I invented:

```
myParser :: Parser [Either String Integer]
myParser = sepBy1 (try (Right . read <$> (some digit <* notFollowedBy (choice [letter, char '-'])))
           <|>          Left         <$>  some (choice [alphaNum, char '-']))
                  (char ' ')
```

My problem is that I don't understand why `try` is needed there (and in any other similar situations). When `try` is not used, an error appears:

```
*Lib>  parseString myParser mempty "123 qwe 123qwe 123-qwe-"
Failure (ErrInfo {_errDoc = (interactive):1:12: error: expected: digit
1 | 123 qwe 123qwe 123-qwe-<EOF>
  |            ^                 , _errDeltas = [Columns 11 11]})
```

So `try` puts the parsing cursor back to where we started on failure. Imagine `try` isn't used:

```
123qwe              
   ^ failed there, the cursor position remains there
```

On the other hand, `<|>` is like "either". It should run the second parser `Left <$> some (choice [alphaNum, char '-']))` (when the first parser failed) and consume just "qwe".
Somewhere I'm wrong.

Comment: In `a <|> b`, if `a` fails, `<|>` will proceed to `b` only if `a` didn’t consume any input, failing otherwise. `try a <|> b` makes `a` backtrack on failure, returning to the state *before* it consumed any input, letting `<|>` proceed. `try` creates a tradeoff between a *simple grammar* and a *fast parser*. The alternative is to refactor your parser to consume input *without* backtracking, then test it to return the appropriate result. Here, a simple solution is `do { cs <- some $ choice [alphaNum, char '-']; pure $ if all isDigit cs then Right (read cs) else Left cs }`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second parser would indeed consume the "qwe" part if only it was given a chance to run. But it isn't given such chance.

Look at [the definition of `(<|>)`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-16.10/trifecta-2.1/src/Text.Trifecta.Parser.html#line-124) for `Parser`:

```
Parser m <|> Parser n = Parser $ \ eo ee co ce d bs ->
  m eo (\e -> n (\a e' -> eo a (e <> e')) (\e' -> ee (e <> e')) co ce d bs) co ce d bs
```

Hmm... Maybe not such a good idea to look at that. But let's push through nevertheless. To make sense of all those `eo`, `ee`, etc., let's look at their explanations [on the `Parser` definition](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-16.10/trifecta-2.1/Text-Trifecta-Parser.html#t:Parser):

> The first four arguments are behavior continuations:
>
> **epsilon success**: the parser has consumed no input and has a result as well as a possible Err; the position and chunk are unchanged (see pure)
>
> **epsilon failure**: the parser has consumed no input and is failing with the given Err; the position and chunk are unchanged (see empty)
>
> **committed success**: the parser has consumed input and is yielding the result, set of expected strings that would have permitted this parse to continue, new position, and residual chunk to the continuation.
>
> **committed failure**: the parser has consumed input and is failing with a given ErrInfo (user-facing error message)

In your case we clearly have "committed failure" - i.e. the `Right` parser has consumed some input and failed. So in this case it's going to call the fourth continuation - denoted `ce` in the definition of `(<|>)`.

And now look at the body of the definition: the fourth continuation is passed to parser `m` unchanged:

```
m eo (\e -> n (\a e' -> eo a (e <> e')) (\e' -> ee (e <> e')) co ce d bs) co ce d bs
                                                                             ^
                                                                             |
                                                                         here it is
```

This means that the parser returned from `(<|>)` will call the fourth continuation in all cases in which parser `m` calls it. Which means that it will fail with "committed failure" in all cases in which the parser `m` fails with "committed failure". Which is exactly what you observe.